# indexeddb - get position of cursor

Tags: cursor, indexeddb

It is possible to advance an indexeddb cursor to a given position:

```
cursor.advance(100)
```

But, is it position to get current position of the cursor? (i.e. return the 100)

Answer (score 1):

No.

You have to keep track of cursor offset yourself. Try to avoid it whenever possible, but instead use keys to locate cursor.